# Established flash game creator application?

Tags: flash

Are there any established/popular Flash Game Creation applications? If so, what are the pros and cons of each. Thanks.

Edit: Sorry, I assumed way to much in the asking of this question. I meant something along the lines of pushbuttonengine.com or similar type flash powered games.

Comment: Not sure this belongs here...

Comment: A tricky one... it is "game-development", so maybe. I know that superuser has a dislike for anything gaming, so that might not be a good move; and it certainly isn't serverfault. So this is probably the most likely place...

Comment: I'm not sure what is asking for... Do you mean game engines? Can we have some examples what is "Flash Game Creation applications"?

Answer (score 2):

Flash itself is setup in a way that, with a small amount of programming and art skill, you can put together pretty simple games.

If you don't have these skills (and aren't interested in spending the time to acquire them) you're looking for something wherein you can drag and drop pregenerated components and click together a game like legos.  The types of games that you can make with these 'engines' will be pretty basic, and you'll most likely exhaust their potential fairly quickly, leaving you to have to learn how to do it 'the right way' anyways...

With that rather lengthy caveat... You can start by just googling for 'flash game creator' and get a few promising looking items. [Sploder](http://sploder.com) is at the top of the list, and that looks kind of interesting, although I haven't tried it myself.

Also, the advantage of learning Flash/Actionscript rather than a proprietary 'engine' is that, when you inevitably run into a problem, there exists much more documentation and community help for Flash and Actionscript than for whatever niche product you'll find.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with JStriedl, better learn AS3 and write our own code, you can use some existing framework for speedy development, but learning AS3 will help in long run.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what type of Flash games you are referring to. There are some specialized game creation kits that work with and generate flash files such as [LASSIE](http://lassie.gmacwill.com) for point-and-click adventure games.

Answer (score 0):

All those link leads to high quality game framework

- FlashPunk, https://github.com/Draknek
- Flixel, http://flixel.org/
- Citrus Engine, http://citrusengine.com/
- Ash Framework (entity based) https://github.com/richardlord/Ash
- Starling (2d GPU accelerated), http://gamua.com/starling/features/

each page describe feature to help you to choose the good one for your game project :)

Answer (score 0):

Quite a broad question. From a point and click angle this is one I have started to tinker with

http://www.alpacaengine.com/

This offers the complete engine/framework for making a point and click game in flash using AS3. The save function, character, stage etc are pre-made for you. You just need design/make the artwork and sfx and everything else.

Alternatively, if you want to start from scratch there a numerous tuts online. Here's one example.

http://monkeypro.net/rosedragon/node/701

Thanks